# How to use jQuery Form Plugin when sending form with live

Tags: jquery, ajax

The plugin:
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit

The code:

```
$( 'form#form' ).live('submit', function( event ){
     if( this.arquivo )
     {
          var options = { 
               success:    showResponse
          }; 

          // pass options to ajaxForm 
          $( '#form' ).ajaxForm( options );         
          $( '#form' ).ajaxSubmit();

          return false;
     }
});


function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
     alert( responseText );
}
```

By submitting the form, function showResponse is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    alert( responseText );
}
var options = {
    success: showResponse
};
//   you dont need to say form#form although i would suggest changing ID name
    // if you're using newer jquery, .live is deprecated to .on and .off
$("#form").on("submit", function(e) {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false; 
});
```

Although, if the form is not created dynamically you're better off using:

```
$("#form").ajaxForm(options);
```

Comment: The form is inserted into the page with ajax. So I was using the 'live'. I changed the version of jQuery and I'm using the 'on', but still did not work.